# SQL Error: ORA-00904: invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to add a foreign key after creating this table

```
Create table Member
(
memeberID int Not null Primary Key,
mebershipID int Not null,
group_id  int not NULL,
Dutycode int not null,
MemberRole varchar(255),
name varchar(255),
last_joined date,
DOB date,
address varchar(255),

CONSTRAINT fk_DutCodes FOREIGN KEY (Dutycode)
REFERENCES RaceManagementDuty(Dutycode),


CONSTRAINT fk_GrMemeberinMemeber FOREIGN KEY (group_id)
REFERENCES Group_member(group_id),

CONSTRAINT fk_Mebersids FOREIGN KEY (mebershipID)
REFERENCES Membership(mebershipID)
)
```

The foreign key I'd like to create is Sailnumber using Alter table:

ALTER TABLE Member
ADD FOREIGN KEY (sailnumber)
REFERENCES Boat(sailnumber)

The sailnumber is the primary key for table boat, as follows

```
Create table Boat
(
sailnumber  int not null Primary Key,
mebershipID  int not NULL,
group_id int not NULL,
sizeOfBoat decimal(5,2),
weight decimal(5,2),
sailarea integer,
numberOfCrew integer,
portsmouthNumber integer,

CONSTRAINT fk_MebersidsBoat FOREIGN KEY (mebershipID)
REFERENCES Membership(mebershipID),


CONSTRAINT fk_GrMemeberinMemebers FOREIGN KEY (group_id)
REFERENCES Group_member(group_id)
)
```

However, I'm getting this error SQL Error: ORA-00904: "SAILNUMBER": invalid identifier, which I am not sure why I'm getting can anybody tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You have no `sailnumber` column in the `Member` table.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `Sailnumber` column to your `Member` table, (before you execute your `add foreign key` query)

```
ALTER TABLE Member ADD sailnumber INT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE Member ADD FOREIGN KEY (sailnumber) REFERENCES Boat(sailnumber);
```

Or in one query:

```
ALTER TABLE member 
ADD sailnumber INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT sailnumber REFERENCES boat(sailnumber);
```